# ReactJS integration with azure SAML SSO

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, single-sign-on, saml

Looking for support on Azure SAML SSO integration with ReactJS and NodeJS application (Non gallery app with custom domain name).

Here are the more details,

1. I have application developed using reactjs (UI) and nodejs (API)
2. Deployed on AWS with custom domain
3. Wanted to integrate with Azure AD via SAML SSO

   - Creating enterprise app with non-gallery application
   - How to configure metadata or certificates for this

Any reference or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889235/how-to-use-azure-ad-as-saml-idp/69895233#69895233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Sign in to the Azure portal using your Azure Active Directory administrator account.

You can add saml sso to non gallery app :
Browse to the Active Directory > Enterprise Applications > New application > Non-gallery application section.

---

[image]

---

This way you can add non-gallery app .

- You can manage claims under attributes and claims. [Customize app
  SAML token claims - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization)

[image]

---

- You can configure SAML certificate  by downloading base 64
  certificate and uploading it as metadata file as shown in sample app
  [here](https://www.cloudfronts.com/blog/azure-office365/how-to-configure-saml-authentication-in-azure-ad-for-zoho-people/)

These apps (app and api)are also present in all applications in app registration where you can add scope for api to the app in  portal and in code and grant permissions to do authentication as usual.

**References:**

1. [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288606/how-to-authenticate-with-azure-ad-accounts-to-react-js-app-with-nodejs-api)
2. [Microsoft identity platform authentication flows & app scenarios |
   Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios)

Comment: Can we integrate SAML SSO with NodeJS adn Azure as Identity provider.   Azure is providing .cer files as cert how to use them, any reference will be highly appreciated